# Melhoramento de codigo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade, para mostrar o beneficio de interatividade do usuário com o jquery.
O modo que fiz foi: 
Content é responsável pela parte de mostrar a imagem e fazer alguma função de onclick.
Porém, na troca de content tenho que retornar o numero do content.
Verificando o código abaixo, vocês tem alguma dica para me dar para que consiga deixar o código mais limpo e melhor para se trabalhar?
Porque nesse código apenas trabalho com 2 contents, porém o meu projeto tenho que trabalhar com 30 contents. vai dar muito trabalho. hehe.
Muito obrigado pessoal! esse site é demais!

CSS:

```
 .slide{
            position:relative;
            width:1000px;
            height:700px;
            margin:0auto;
        }
        .slide img {
            position: absolute;

        }
        .content-switcher{
            display:none;
        }

        .clicarinicio {
            width: 130px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 5px solid #FF0000;
            position: absolute;
            display:none;
            bottom:0;

        }

        .clicarinicio2 {
            width: 130px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 5px solid blue;
            position: absolute;
            display:none;
            top:0;

        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slide">
        <div class="content-switcher" id="Content1">
            <img src="img/1inicio.jpg" style="height:100%;" />
            <div class="mostraBox" style="display:none;width:100px;height: 20px; right:0; position: absolute; color: white;">Clique no botao Iniciar</div>
            <div class="clicarinicio"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="content-switcher" id="Content2">
            <img src="img/2botao.jpg" style="height:100%;" />
            <div class="mostraBox2" style="display:none;width:100px;height: 20px; right:0; position: absolute; color: white;">Abriu o painel! Clique em Alguma coisa</div>
            <div class="clicarinicio2"></div>

        </div>




    </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            selectStep(1);

             $('.clicarinicio').on('click', function () {
                 return selectStep(2);
                });


        }); //FIM DE DOCUMENT READY


        function selectStep(n) {


            if (n == 1) {

                $('.clicarinicio').fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).show();
                $('.mostraBox').fadeIn("slow").delay(10000).show();
            }

            if (n == 2) {

                $('.clicarinicio2').fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).show();
                $('.mostraBox2').fadeIn("slow").delay(10000).show();
            }

            $(".content-switcher").hide();
            $("#Content" + n).show();
        }
```

Comment: você pode passar o proprio elemento DOM para sua função `selectStep` e trabalhar com ele dentro.

Comment: obrigado por responder Rafael. Pode me dar um exemplo por favor?

Comment: Deixa ver se eu entendi;
Quando você clica "mostrarBox" uma outra caixa é exibida certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode começar organizando melhor o HTML, os elementos não precisam ter um ID para você capturar seu clique ou o elemento em sí, por exemplo;

```
<div class="slide">

<div class="content-switcher">
    <button class="mostraBox">
      Clique - conteudo 1
    </button>
    <div class="box">Conteudo 1</div>
</div>

<div class="content-switcher">
    <button class="mostraBox">
      Clique - conteudo 2
    </button>
    <buton class="box">Conteudo 2</button>
</div>
```

Assim você pode adicionar quantos `content-switcher`você quiser...

Para capturar a ação de click faça;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mostraBox').on('click', function() { // Captura o click
        $(this).next('.box').fadeIn('slow'); 
        // Pega o proximo elemento 
        // (abaixo da div .mostrabox que é a div onde esta o conteudo) 
        // e aplica o efeito fadeIn.
    });
});
```

Note que você não precisa colocar ID's nos elementos pois existem classes no jquery onde você pode manipular até os elementos ao redor do alvo em que você capturou o click.

Ao usar a função `next()` tome cuidado pois se você ou alguém precisar alterar o layout e adicionar outra div entre `.box` e `.mostraBox` o script não irá funcionar, porém podemos utilizar outro modo também, veja no exemplo abaixo;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.mostraBox').on('click', function() { // Captura o click
      $(this).parent().find('.box').fadeIn('slow'); 
   });
});
```

Com a função `parent()` você busca a div que esta "acima" do botão (no caso `content-switcher`) e busca DENTRO da `content-switcher` uma div com class `.box`, deste modo você pode adicionar qualquer outra div dentro da `content-switcher` que o script continuara funcionando.

Comment: Otimo! muito obrigado por responder. Essa forma de pegar outro elemento é fantastico! Obrigado rafael.

Comment: @JoaoMarcos que bom que a resposta ajudou, note que deste modo você pode criar 1000 divs com os mesmos elementos e mesmo assim continuara funcionando, apenas tome cuidado com o `next()` pois se você por acabo precisar mudar o layout e adicionar uma outra div entre o `box` e o `mostraBox` não vai funcionar.

Comment: @JoaoMarcos adicionei mais exemplos na resposta, veja se entende.